# Makefile gtkmm; collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, mingw, gtkmm

I'm pretty sure the problem lays somewhere in my makefile, as when I make the program, the error in the title points me to line 12, the linker command.  I've tinkered around for it with a while but can't seem to get anything to work.  The following is my code/makefile.  I am making this in mingw32.

makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -g $(shell pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags)
LDLIBS = -lpthread $(shell pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs)

all: test

test: sample.count

sample.count: InIT_Printer_Install_Assistant
    ./InIT_Printer_Install_Assistant

InIT_Printer_Install_Assistant: main.o win_home.o
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@ $^ `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`

main.o: main.cpp win_home.h
win_home.o: win_home.cpp win_home.h

clean:
    -rm -f *.o *~

spotless: clean
    -rm -f InIT_Printer_Install_Assistant
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "win_home.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "com.InIT.PrinterApp");

    HomeGUI win_home;

    win_home.set_default_size(600,400);
    win_home.set_title("InIT Self-Service Printer Management");

    return app->run(win_home);
}
```

win_home.cpp:

```
#include "win_home.h"

HomeGUI::HomeGUI()
{
    //build interface/gui
    this->buildInterface();


    //retrieve printers

    //create printer Buttons

    //register Handlers
    //this->registerHandlers();
}

void HomeGUI::buildInterface()
{
    //combo boxes
    /*
    Gtk::HBox combo_rowbox = Gtk::HBox(false, 10);
    Gtk::ComboBox combobox_department = Gtk::ComboBox(false);
    Gtk::ComboBox combobox_building = Gtk::ComboBox(false);
    combo_rowbox.pack_start(child, false, false, padding=0)
    add(combo_rowbox);
    */
    return;
}
```

win_home.h:

```
#ifndef GTKMM_INIT_PRINTER_INSTALL_ASSISTANT_H
#define GTKMM_INIT_PRINTER_INSTALL_ASSISTANT_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>

class HomeGUI : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    HomeGUI();
    virtual ~HomeGUI();

    void buildInterface();
    void registerHandlers();
    //void defaultToFloorPlan();
protected:
    //Signal Handlers

    //Member variables
    std::string m_selected_department;
    std::string m_selected_building;
    std::string m_selected_floor;

    //Member widgets
    //std::vector<Gtk::Button> m_printbuttons;
    //HelpGUI m_win_help;
    //UninstallGUI m_win_uninstall;

    //Member logic
    //ClientLogic logic;
};

#endif
```

Result after making:

C:\msys32\home\PrintApplication/win_home.cpp:3: undefined reference to `VTT for HomeGUI'
C:\msys32\home\PrintApplication/win_home.cpp:3: undefined reference to`VTT for HomeGUI'
C:\msys32\home\PrintApplication/win_home.cpp:3: undefined reference to `vtable for HomeGUI'
C:\msys32\home\PrintApplication/win_home.cpp:3: undefined reference to`vtable for HomeGUI'
C:\msys32\home\PrintApplication/win_home.cpp:3: undefined reference to `vtable for HomeGUI'
C:\msys32\home\PrintApplication/win_home.cpp:3: undefined reference to`vtable for HomeGUI'
C:\msys32\home\PrintApplication/win_home.cpp:3: undefined reference to `VTT for HomeGUI'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:12: InIT_Printer_Install_Assistant] Error 1

If anyone can enlighten me as to why this is happening, that would be greatly appreciated.

**Note: as you can tell, I'm still a noob with makefiles, so feel free to correct me as needed when it comes to general makefile formatting.

Comment: `virtual ~HomeGUI() {};` Non-pure virtual functions must have a body. And a destructor must always have a body, even if it is pure virtual. (You'll also need a body for `RegisterHandlers`).

Comment: Now I feel dumb.  Thanks so much!  Looks like it worked!

Answer (score 0):

@Unimportant's comment solved the issue.  Both pure virtual and non-pure virtual functions must all have a body.  Changed my win_home.h to:

```
#include "win_home.h"

HomeGUI::HomeGUI()
{
    //build interface/gui
    this->buildInterface();


    //retrieve printers

    //create printer Buttons

    //register Handlers
    //this->registerHandlers();
}
HomeGUI::~HomeGUI()
{

}

void HomeGUI::buildInterface()
{
    //combo boxes
    /*
    Gtk::HBox combo_rowbox = Gtk::HBox(false, 10);
    Gtk::ComboBox combobox_department = Gtk::ComboBox(false);
    Gtk::ComboBox combobox_building = Gtk::ComboBox(false);
    combo_rowbox.pack_start(child, false, false, padding=0)
    add(combo_rowbox);
    */
    return;
}

void HomeGUI::registerHandlers()
{

}
```